# How to move "Choose file" to the right of "No file chosen" in <input type = "file"/> with css

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a way to change the placement of "Choose File" and "No file chosen" so that the "No file chosen" area appears before "Choose File". I don't want to change any html, I only want to change the css.

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="files[submission_1]" size="22" class="form-file" />
```

here to save time
http://jsfiddle.net/x8wCu/

Comment: No. The browser determines how to display it. You can create your own in Chrome and Firefox that use a hidden file input. But it takes some hacky javascript and is not nice.

Comment: @mplungjan: Nope. That moves everything.

Comment: @mmm I did not see what he meant when I read it

Comment: @Emanegux - Except it's actually not that simple. If you read that whole question, you'll understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible because the browser decides how that is displayed.

However you can customise the way it looks by using a hack. You basically hide your file input by setting `opacity` to `0` and then putting a `div` on top of it.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fengelz/28x7Y/).

Comment: Quite a fine hack there. This will help me a lot.

Comment: That's a strange url in the fiddle. O.o